# How to adjust div max-height on browser open and reinitialize

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay I have a div class "content"  and whenever the browser resizes to 800px in height the content div resizes its max-height to 500px.  The problem I am having is if the browser opens with a height of 800px then there is no scrollbar for the div unless I refresh the browser.

The code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('resize', function(){
if($(this).height() <= 800){
    $('.content').css('max-height', '500px'); //set max height
}else{
    $('.content').css('max-height', ''); //delete attribute
}
});
</script>
```

Also I am using jScrollPane and it works fine if I set the max-height in the css but if I use the code above instead a regular scrollbar is used.  Any help on either would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use the same function on 'load' event?

Comment: No I am not sure how to do that.  I am not that great with jQuery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(window).on('resize', function(){
     if ($(this).height() <= 800){
          $('.content').css('max-height', '500px'); //set max height
     } else{
          $('.content').css('max-height', ''); 
     }
   }).resize()

})
```

Comment: Okay this works.  Now for the scrollbar, have you used jscrollpane?  Is there a reason why it won't allow the function we used above?  It works if I don't use max height but if I use it then it display regular scrollbar.

Comment: @AnthonyRusso Sorry I haven't used that plugin.

Comment: No problem.  I will work with it a little more and then post a new question.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Call that code once in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @AnthonyRusso `$(document).ready(function(){ // your codes })`

Comment: It still works and shows a scrollbar when the window is resized but if I open the page in my browser when it's set to 800px in height it has no scrollbar.

Comment: @AnthonyRusso Try my answer. you should trigger the resize event.

Comment: @undefined.  I am confused how do I use your answer with the document ready that I just added from your previous reply?

Comment: @AnthonyRusso Sorry for the confusion, please try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in

```
$(function() {
    //Script in here should run on document.ready
});
```